# Report server databases

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

For which purposes serve two databases in my SQL Management Studio:

- ReportServer$InstanceName
- ReportServer$InstanceNameTempDB

I know that it is installed together with reporting services, but I don't know much about them.

Comment: [MSDN SQL Server Books Online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159106.aspx) has **TONS** of documentation on SQL Server Reporting Services, including an extensive chapter on [Reporting Services database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156016.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The descriptions of the databases used by SSRS can be found [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156016.aspx) <--

Answer (score 3):

The ReportServer database contains all of the objects for Reporting Services.  It includes reports, linked reports, shared data sources, subscriptions, folders, report models, uploaded files, schedules, snapshots, report execution logs, object-level security settings, etc.  It needs to be backed up regularly along with its encryption keys.  If you are building out a reporting solution, then this database gives you just about everything you need for auditing purposes.

The ReportServerTempDB is what it sounds like -- a database full of temporary objects.  You can literally delete all the contents of the tables in the database and you won't lose anything permanent.  You still need to back it up in case you need to restore it in a DR situation, but you should never need to query anything in it.